# adding "workday" into an "if" statement in an excel formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I want this function to only list workdays of the month. I tried searching for workday implementation in an if function but wasn't able to get something working.

```
=IF(ROWS(A$1:A1)>DAY(I$3);"";$I$2+ROWS(A$1:A1)-1)
```

[excel snippet] https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Sp6j.jpg

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in a cell at the top of the worksheet and fill down.

```
=WORKDAY(I$2-1, ROW(1:1))
```

Add a holiday list and/or compensate for `IF(WORKDAY(I$2-1, ROW(1:1))>I$3, ...` to avoid overruns into  the next month.